# Adding multiple touch listeners inside canvas Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

Suppose I have multiple drawings in my canvas, how can I add touch listener for each of the drawings seperately inside that canvas?

I will be having different drawings like star, circle, rectangle etc etc added dynamically how can I handle each of them ?

I couldn find ans in SO  the very close question was this [Set touch listeners on canvas drawings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413370/set-touch-listeners-on-canvas-drawings) but it has no ans.

Help and suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633545/android-imageview-scaling-and-translating-issue

Comment: short version: you have to store your shapes and see if the X and Y of onTouch matches(with offset) any of the shapes X and Y, this is how I done it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't add any **touch listener** on the **drawings** of your **canvas**. You have to add the listener in your **view** then **onTouchEvent** you will get the **x, y coordinates** of user touch then have to calculate by your own if the **touch location** is any of your **drawings** .

For example

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        int touchX, touchY;

    touchX = (int) event.getX();
    touchY = (int) event.getY();

    if ((touchX > (cntWidth / 2) && touchX < (scrnWidth - (cntWidth / 2)))) && ((touchY > cntHeight / 2 && touchY < (scrnHeight - (cntHeight / 2)))) {                      
        int col, row;

        // Here you will check

    }
}
```